# C# - Perform NAT between tap-win32 interface and a physical network interface

Tags: c#, .net, networking, interface, network-programming

[Here](http://www.varsanofiev.com/inside/TunTest.cs) is a simple C# code example on how to read packets from a TAP interface, switch the source IP with the destination IP in the packet and send it back on the TAP interface.

What I want to do is perform NAT between the TAP interface and two physical network interfaces (load balancing). So I get the packets from TAP interface, modify the source IP in the IP packet, send it on one of the two physical interfaces and map sIP:sPort - dIP:dPort to the that interface. Then to all of the incoming packets on that physical interface, I change the destination IP to the one of the TAP interface, and send them to the TAP interface.

For TAP interface, in the example, this is done by calling FileCreate(device...) which returns a handle that is passed to FileStream constructor. Then to read/write from the stream, methods BeginRead and BeginWrite are used.

My question is how do you read/write packets from a physical network interface in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're on a Windows machine (as your referenced code sample is Windows-specific), the ability to read/write raw packets from/to a network adapter isn't a feature that comes from the Microsoft factory :-)  You'll need some sort of kernel component that can act as a protocol device (like Tcpip.sys) and bind to various miniports (network adapters).  Here are a few examples I know of:

WinPcap - Primarily used for packet capture/sniffing, but has a interface for sending packets, too. http://www.winpcap.org/

Rawether - http://www.rawether.net/

Comment: I see. WinPcap uses a driver called NPF to do what you just described. Looks like I have to dive in winpcap library :P